# eclipse not showing artifacts when creating new maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

[image]
Hello Guys,

I am new to both maven and spring. I want to create a maven based spring project and Here is what I am doing.

New->other -> maven project -> next -> next -> ?

Here I want to select a type of project with required folder set up. For example to set up a simple maven based java project i select maven-archetype-quickstart . But coming to spring I dont know which artifact to select and I have the feeling that it is not showing all the artifacts. I am attaching some screenshots of that step where I got confused.

To be more brief:
1) If I want to get a spring project which artifact should I select
2) It looks like I am not able to see all artifacts here. For example when I look for spring I see only two artifacts. when I search for webapp i see only two artifacts. Should I do any configurations?
3)How to know which artifact suites for example for basic spring project which artifact should I choose?

My questions might be pretty basic. Please help me

Thanks

[image: All artifacts I am able to see][image: artifacts related to spring![][2]]

Answer (score 1):

The `appfuse-basic-spring` archetype should create a single directory spring project. This is probably what you want for a simple project.
The `appfuse-modular-spring` should create a multi-module (read: parent module with several child modules) project. For more information on multi-module maven projects I would suggest looking at chapters 6 and 7 of [Maven by Example](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/public-book.html).